Puppeteer works from console but not when called from PHP on Cpanel VPS
I have a script I that creates pdf using puppeteer, this script is called by a php page using shell_exec. This used to work on my previous server but now my hosting has migrated my VPS on a new system (now running on Cloudlinux 8.10). I'm trying to make this script work again but I can't find a fix for my issue
this is how the script is called from the php script
$html = shell_exec("node " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/pdf.js " . $url . " 2>&1");

And this is how I launch the browser in the script
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
const [page] = await browser.pages();

Both the previous VPS and this one use Apache 2.4 and Cpanel (the new one uses version 122.0.26, I don't remember which version was used on the old one) and I don't remember doing anything special to make this work.
When I run it from the console (using root or another user) it works fine, but when I run it from the php page it doesn't and if I check the output I see this error
Failed to launch the browser process! ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/partition_address_space.cc(49) 
Check failed: reserved_base_address_ TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md 

I checked the troubleshooting page, and looked on the internet for this error, but found nothing that helped (a lot of unanswered questions with this error though)
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6978
Puppeteer on Centos cPanel: Failed to launch the browser process
https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/Q3VoQBZxsJU
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40185289
Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer
EDIT:
I tried running a PHP script with shell_exec from the console and it still works, meanwhile I noticed the Apache server is running with the user "nobody", maybe this user is limited on what it can do?
EDIT 2:
I found this
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2441
and ran these commands:
sudo setfacl -dR -m g:nobody:rX  node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/
sudo setfacl -R -m g:nobody:rX  node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/

At first it didn't work, but then I added a global installation of chromium on the server using
yum install chromium-browser

and then ran the same commands as above on /usr/bin/chromium/browser
Now I have a different error, or better it just says
Failed to launch the browser process! 

Without any other detail...it's progress i guess
EDIT 3: The user launching the script is not "nobody" but another user created by cPanel, it didn't have shell access and I gave it to the user, but still not working when called from the browser (it works when I call it from the console using this user)

Do you have the error log ? It would help pinpoint the exact issue here.

That's the problem: I couldn't get any log. I tried core dumps, the dumpIO option from puppeteer, var/log/messages and more. Nothing :(

did you run node pdf.js url on the console before?

@emild_ yes and it works fine, even when run with the same user that runs the php scripts in apache

make sure you place the string into variable and var_dump, then node using absolute path, you can try whereis node on the console to find absolute path

Is it possible that you need to set an env var?

Do you have SELinux enabled by chance? You could disabled it temporarily setenforce 0 then see if it works. If it does, then re-enable it (setenforce 1) and then look at /var/log/audit/audit.log for the error message.

what env var should I set? @MagnieMozios SELinux is disabled
